# Need help for setting up completion for C/C++ with deoplete and neovim

Tags: autocompletion, neovim

I'm having some trouble to enable C/C++ completion with deoplete.

I don't know what plugins I should really install and how to configure deoplete to work with them.

I read that for C/C++ completion vim-marching is recommanded, but is it a plugin that would feed deoplete or a completion plugin on itself?

In vim-marching documentation, it says that it requires vim-proc, also and I see some configurations with neocomplete.

Shougo plugins are like an ecosystem with interdependencies and excuse my poor ignorance but I really don't understand who does what, even after reading the (not always explicit) github pages and documentations.

If someone would have the kindness to explains me how to configure C/C++ completion with Shougo's plugins I would really be grateful.

Thank you

*Edit:*

**My configuration for deoplete is:**

```
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 0
if !exists('g:deoplete#omni#input_patterns')
  let g:deoplete#omni#input_patterns = {}
endif
```

I tried it because I got a lot of error at first without it, and now if I disable that configuration I get `Option 'omnifunc' is not set.

**Whith clang_complete I tried this:**

```
let g:clang_complete_auto = 0
let g:clang_auto_select = 0
let g:clang_default_keymappings = -1
```

Comment: Are you talking about omni completion? Did you tried Ctrl+x Ctrl+o (both together) when typing a c program?

Comment: I think you confuse vim and neovim completion methods in your post. AFAIK, you only need Shougo's 'deoplete' and 'RipRip/clang_complete' for neovim, both properly configured (I remember Shougo did write about how to configure both to work together).

Comment: For omni completion I get the error `Pattern not found` and with 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete' `<C-x><C-u>` I get the error `Option 'completefunc' is not set`. I put my configuration in the post.
I can't find the post from Shougo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from the python support in neovim, plugins like clang_complete and deoplete needs python support.

To check if python is supported, `:echo has('python')` should print 1.

If it prints 0, you need to install the python library python-neovim with `pip` or you're distribution's package manager if a package exists.

I use Archlinux and packages exists, there is two packages: `python-neovim` and `python2-neovim`, the first one being for Python3 and the latter for Python2. For me **both packages needed to be installed** to enable Python support, and that is where the problem came from.